# How to extract consecutive email addresses from text in C#

Tags: c#, regex, email

I have the following three examples of strings:

string1 = "abcd@efg.com this is just some text. these are just some numbers 123456 xyz@xyz.com asdasd asdad"

string2 = "abcd@efg.com mnop@qrs.com This is just some text. these are just some numbers 123456 xyz@xyz.com asdasd asd"

string3 = "abcd@efg.com mnop@qrs.com uvw@xyz.com This is just some text. these are just some numbers 123456 xyz@xyz.com asdad"

Final output should be a List consisting of all the emails that appear consecutively at the beginning of the string.

Output for string1 - one email address

Output for string3 - three email addresses

Address "xyz@xyz.com" should be ignored as it appears between some other text.
Is there any solution for this?
The existing method returns all the addresses.

```
    private List<string> ExtractEmails(string strStringGoesHere)
    {
        List<string> lstExtractedEmails = new List<string>();
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match match;
        for (match = reg.Match(strStringGoesHere); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
        {
            if (!(lstExtractedEmails.Contains(match.Value)))
            {
                lstExtractedEmails.Add(match.Value);
            }
        }
        return lstExtractedEmails;
    }
```

Comment: what about [this](https://regex101.com/r/vcUbCV/2)

Comment: Thnx MJN.. but it didn't wrk fr me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `\G` anchor that only matches at the start of the string and then at the end of each successful match:

```
@"(?i)\G\s*([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})"
```

See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5CG%7C%5E%29%5Cs*%28%5BA-Z0-9._%25%2B-%5D%2B%40%5BA-Z0-9.-%5D%2B%5C.%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%2C6%7D%29&i=abcd%40efg.com%20this%20is%20just%20some%20text.%20these%20are%20just%20some%20numbers%20123456%20xyz%40xyz.com%20asdasd%20asdad%0D%0A%0D%0Aabcd%40efg.com%20mnop%40qrs.com%20This%20is%20just%20some%20text.%20these%20are%20just%20some%20numbers%20123456%20xyz%40xyz.com%20asdasd%20asd%0D%0A%0D%0Aabcd%40efg.com%20mnop%40qrs.com%20uvw%40xyz.com%20This%20is%20just%20some%20text.%20these%20are%20just%20some%20numbers%20123456%20xyz%40xyz.com%20asdad&o=im)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - inline case insensitive flag
- `\G` - anchor that only matches at the start of the string and at the end of each successful match
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})` - Group 1 matching an email like substring (there are [*other patterns that you may use here*](http://emailregex.com/), but generally, it is something like `\S+@\S+\.\S+`).

[***C# demo***](https://ideone.com/ND0TgR):

```
var strs = new List<string> {"abcd@efg.com this is just some text. these are just some numbers 123456 xyz@xyz.com asdasd asdad",
    "abcd@efg.com mnop@qrs.com This is just some text. these are just some numbers 123456 xyz@xyz.com asdasd asd",
    "abcd@efg.com mnop@qrs.com uvw@xyz.com This is just some text. these are just some numbers 123456 xyz@xyz.com asdad" };
foreach (var s in strs) 
{
    var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?i)\G\s*([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
}
```

Results:

```
abcd@efg.com
abcd@efg.com, mnop@qrs.com
abcd@efg.com, mnop@qrs.com, uvw@xyz.com
```

Comment: Only you probably want to trim whitespaces for each match.

Comment: @AndriiNikolaienko No need to, the necessary data in Group 1.

Comment: In the regexStorm link, you have used `(\G|^)`. Why is `\G` not sufficient there?

Comment: @Gurman Since it is a demo with a multiline string, I have to add `^` alternative as `\G` can only match at the beginning of the whole string, `RegexOptions.Multiline` option does not change its behavior. In real code, `\G` is enough.